# Invalid src prop

Tags: next.js, bots, sanity

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfmWA.png)

can some body help me with this.

code:

```
const SampleImageComponent = ({ value, isInline }) => {
  const { width, height } = getImageDimensions(value);
  return (
    <Image
      src={urlBuilder()
        .image(value)
        .width(isInline ? 100 : 800)
        .url()}
      alt={value.alt || 'No image'}
      loading='lazy'
      style={{
        // Display alongside text if image appears inside a block text span
        display: isInline ? 'inline-block' : 'block',

        // Avoid jumping around with aspect-ratio CSS property
        aspectRatio: width / height,
      }}
      width={100}
      height={100}
    />
  );
};
const components = {
  types: {
    image: SampleImageComponent,
    // Any other custom types you have in your content
    // Examples: mapLocation, contactForm, code, featuredProjects, latestNews, etc.
  },
};

<PortableText value={blog.body} components={components} />;
```

This code is working. i guess the error is from backend.

there is undefined mention in url in error image.

this error pop up when i change img tag to Image tag.

i'm new to coding

using sanity and next js

domain is already config in next.config.js

Comment: Can you please share the code for your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: module.exports = {
 reactStrictMode: true,
 swcMinify: true,
 images: {
  domains: ['cdn.sanity.io']
  
 }
};

// /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
// const nextConfig = {
  
// }


// module.exports = nextConfig

Comment: Remove the last two lines of that `next.config.js` - it's overriding the actual images config.